# How to color some numbers on a line and add a shade

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles

Questions:

- In figure (1) I want to give blue color to 0 (Zero)
- In figure (2) I want to shade the numbers (figure is attached)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
Figure (1)

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
        \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{};
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{
            \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\ifnum\x>0\color{blue}\fi\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1.5cm}
Figure (2)

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{};
    \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers:

1. instead of `>0` use `>-1`
2. draw another line of the color you like

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
Figure (1)

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
        \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{};
        \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}{
            \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\ifnum\x>-1\color{blue}\fi\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1.5cm}
Figure (2)

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
    \draw[line width=5mm, green, yshift=2.5mm] (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{};
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Really it was easy.

Comment: You should use ` \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}`.

Comment: @projetmbc I copied the OP's MWE and didn't notice that, thank you for pointing it out. I updated my answer.

Comment: @SandyM You're welcome, see also projetmbc's comment and my renewed answer. It's not necessary to list all the numbers in the `\foreach`. Thank you for accepting.